# UITapGestureRecognizer not recognizing taps

Tags: ios, subview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a viewcontroller programatically and added a sub view on the upper half of the view controller. However when I try to add tap gestures to my subview it does not seem to recognise the taps.When I tap on the sub view(menuSubView) pointer does not call the -(void) tapGestureMethod.

Below is my code-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapMenuSubView=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureMethod:)];
   tapMenuSubView.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
   tapMenuSubView.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
   tapMenuSubView.delegate=self;
   self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   self.menuSubView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   [self.menuSubView addGestureRecognizer:tapMenuSubView];
}
-(void)tapGestureMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
     UIView *tapView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview: tapView];
}
```

Comment: Where you added self.menuSubView to your main view ?

Comment: check the isUserInteractionEnabled in subview. it should be enabled.

Comment: I have added that in viewdidLoad method itself.

Comment: @Jeyamahesan yes, it is enabled. I hope you are referring to "self.menuSubView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;"

Comment: @TejasviTandon please add that stuff also.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh is it ok if I put the files on dropbox and provide you the link? I think there is a problem in my view itself.

Comment: set clips to bounds true of each view there, and check are you able to see that view or not

Comment: @MikeAlter no, it does not work.

Comment: are you able to see that view ? if not that check frames of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you sent it's hard to say, what might be a problem. We don't know, what's inside a `menuSubView`'s class, how do you create `menuSubView`, etc.

Without knowing it, I would suggest to remove temporarily the `tapMenuSubView.delegate=self;`. It depends on your logic, but in the basic case, you don't need the delegate to make a gesture recognizer work.

If it doesn't help, I would go deeper into a setup of the `menuSubView` to ensure nothing intercepts taps. Maybe, there's an invisible view which covers it. Or other gesture recognizers which might cause problems.

**UPDATE**

The problem is in this method.

```
- (IBAction)menuButton:(id)sender {
    MenuViewViewController *menuViewObj=[[MenuViewViewController alloc]init];
    menuViewObj.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-80, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [menuViewObj.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:menuViewObj.view];
}
```

You don't correctly embed `MenuViewViewController` into `ViewController`. [This tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) should help.

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *) content {
   [self addChildViewController:content];
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];  // set any frame you like
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu6v1ir0fqzquba/MenuViewViewController.m?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4anb8yk4g6y9qa/MenuViewViewController.h?dl=0

Comment: these are the links to my ViewController and MenuViewController files. In the view controller i have created a button. when you tap that button, MenuViewController is created with one view at upper half and one table at lower half. Now what  I want is if I tap on the upper half view it should perform a specific action. but it is not performing that. And also lower half table's data is disappearing when i scroll that. If possible please have a look at this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go through that guide and will try to correct my mistakes.

Comment: @TejasviTandon enjoy :) Honestly, there're multiple things in unussual way. If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code;

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
    {
    return YES;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it does not work. I have posted the links of file above. And also explained the scenario, Please have a look at that if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
You are adding on menuSubview. Either add it on self.view or try to get it from menuSubview.

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapMenuSubView=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureMethod:)];
   tapMenuSubView.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
   tapMenuSubView.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
   tapMenuSubView.delegate=self;
   self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapMenuSubView];
}

-(void)tapGestureMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    UIView *tapView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview: tapView];
}
```

Comment: Do you have another view on self.view?

Comment: If Yes, then you should adopt the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol inside the self object and call the below method for checking the view. Inside this method, check your view against touch.view and return the appropriate bool (Yes/No). Something like this:


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourSubView]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}